# TextField() sometimes stays BOLDING even when HTML style was reset with setTextFormat()

Tags: actionscript-3, flex3

Any ideas why TextField() sometimes keeps **BOLDING** (even when the format was reset with setTextFormat()) like this?:

```
myFormat.bold=false;
defaultTextFormat =myFormat;  
defaultTextFormat.bold = false;
setTextFormat(myFormat);

htmlText("This text is bold even when it should not be.")
```

PS: TextField is editable and the problem occurs when it is edited by user.

UPDATE: I want to get rid of all formatting to avoid the unwanted **BOLD**. TextField has a bug that when a bolded word is backspaced over by the user, everything in TextField is bolded forever.

Comment: Could you elaborate, what you mean by "problem occurs when it is edited by user"? Does this mean that boldface is removed, but it is reapplied when user starts to edit?  Or that new text entered by the user is still bold, despite changing the defaultTextFormat?

Comment: textfield has content with different styles/formats,  when user is backspacing to a word that is BOLD  the whole textfield goes to BOLD,  there is no way to get it back to not-bold.  It remains bold for ever.  How can I reset it to non-bold?

Comment: But why do you use the "myFormat.bold" if you are setting the style with html tags in the same time ? Actually if you only set the styles with html/css flash handles the user interaction seamlessly.

Comment: I am actually using just HTML tags,  but when  user backspaces a word that has BOLD tag  the whole Textfield goes to weird BOLD mode, I am just trying now to get rid of BOLD mode with code rows above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that with the TextField control you need to set the TextFeild.styleSheet to change the HTML style.  Try something like this:

```
var myText:TextField = new TextField();
var style:StyleSheet = new StyleSheet();
var fonts:String = "Helvetica Neue, Arial, _sans";
style = new StyleSheet();
style.setStyle(".body", {fontFamily:fonts, fontSize:"12", fontWeight:"normal", color:"#222222", textDecoration:"none"});
myText.styleSheet = style;
myText.htmlText = "this is bold even when should not";
```